# Python library to convert full currency names to their appropriate abbreviation

Tags: python, currency

I have a list of currencies as:

```
       'United States dollar', 'European Euro', 'Indian rupee',
       'Pound sterling', 'Canadian dollar', 'Brazilian real',
       'Australian dollar', 'Polish zloty', 'Russian ruble', 'Swedish krona',
       ...
       'Macanese pataca', 'Samoan tala', 'Libyan dinar', 'Namibian dollar',
       'Cayman Islands dollar', 'Fijian dollar', 'Lesotho loti',
       'Turkmen manat', 'Somali shilling', 'Mozambican metical'
```

Are their any existing libraries that can help me convert these names to their proper abbreviations
For example:

```
United States dollar -- USD
European Euro -- EUR
Indian Rupee -- INR etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of this JSON data to find the abbreviations and symbols
https://gist.github.com/stevekinney/8334552.
Through this, you can iterate through the data and can easily find the symbol and abbreviation with their names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This Library [iso4217parse](https://pypi.org/project/iso4217parse/)

For instance-

```
a = 'United States dollar'
text = iso4217parse.by_symbol_match(a.strip())

text
[Currency(alpha3='USD', code_num=840, name='United States dollar', 
symbols=['US$', '$', '＄', '﹩', 'dollar', 'dollars', 'Dollar', 
'Dollars', 'US＄', 'US﹩'], minor=2, countries=['AS', 'BB', 'BM', 'BQ', 
'EC', 'FM', 'GU', 'HT', 'IO', 'MH', 'MP', 'PA', 'PR', 'PW', 'SV', 'TC', 
'TL', 'UM', 'US', 'VG', 'VI'])]

currency = str(text[0][3][1])+' '+str(text[0][2])
```

Output-

```
'$ United States dollar' 
 # in the current case, the text variable will need
 # to be parsed in order to get alpha3='USD'
```

**Although**, test as to what output it gives for a few currencies, rarely it gave a different currency for a symbol with regard to the project requirements.